# Cannot find apksigner through command line in windows

Tags: android, google-play, apk, build-tools, apksigner

I'm trying to sign my android app with apksigner.

Typing this command

```
apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.jks my-app.apk
```

Gives the error `sh.exe": apksigner: command not found`

While adding 'bat' `apksigner.bat sign --ks my-release-key.jks my-app.apk`

gives me the error

```
    /c/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/apksigner.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found
/c/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/apksigner.bat: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/c/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/apksigner.bat: line 2: `REM Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project'
```

I made sure I have android build tools folder in my PATH, and that apksigner.bat is present there.
Typing something like `apksigner sign --help` and `apksigner.bat sign --help` gives the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

From the path in your question it looks like you are on a windows machine, but all the pathnames you give have '/' paths, which don't look like Windows paths. Can you give more details of your environment? It looks like you might be using something like cygwin, and the problem is there.

Comment: Use apksigner --help or apksigner --version, it should work